# How to structure firebase database with categories and subcategories?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

Hello i want to create firebase database for groceries store. I have categories and under each category i have subcategories and some of these subcategories has sub-subcategories and under those there are products. how can i structure that in firebase database?
[firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aieQS.png)

Comment: Structuring your Firebase Database depends on the use-cases that you want to implement in your app. That makes this type of question (especially when you don't have a proposal yet of what you're considering and the use-cases you're concerned about) a bit broad for Stack Overflow. I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) for a good introduction to the topic of data modeling.

Comment: Thank you for the links. i have use-case i have a list of categories and when i click on one of them it will check in the firebase if it has subcategory or not
If it has subcategory then will view it as list and so on
If there is no subcategory it will search for all the product under this category or subcategory and view it as list. how the the firebase structure for category and it is sub and products?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

there i would suggest this way, may be it'll helpful.

[image]

as you can see above image, i have a category tree, following which consists of two child nodes which Category and ParentId. In your case i will suggest get all categories where parentId equal to Zero.

```
firebase.database().ref("Category").orderByChild("ParentId").equalTo(0);
```

which will return all Categories. then when you click a category query like below

```
firebase.database().ref("Category").orderByChild("ParentId").equalTo("Pass your Category Id here");
```

which will return all sub-categories based on the Category that you choosed.

In your case, you can add another child node like SubCategoryParentId for your subcategories which has subcategories and query like below

```
firebase.database().ref("Category").orderByChild("SubCategoryParentId").equalTo("Pass your Subcategory Id here");
```

which will return all subcategories for the subcategories you choosed.